# Gibbs function for pure substances

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I know that the Gibbs function for pure substances is given by

$$\mathrm dG = V\,\mathrm dp - S\,\mathrm dT.\tag{1}$$

However, I also saw the same equation in the form

$$ΔG = VΔp - SΔT,\tag{2}$$

however I am doubtful if the second equation is correct as now $Δ$ represents finite changes which is different from the infinitesimal changes in the first equation. Is the second equation correct?

Comment: Maybe.  It depends on whether you are OK approximating $V(P, T)$ as a constant $V$ and $S(P, T)$ as a constant $S$.

Comment: The 2nd equation is not correct.

Comment: Well,i saw in an pdf from Massachusetts Institute Of Technology where they have used d(∆G)/dP=ΔV (at constant temperature)..from where did they get this equation then?

Comment: What is the source of the second equation in your post? The equation from the MIT pdf is ok, it is taken from eq 1 at constant T, when looking at the difference in G for two states.

Comment: BTW make sure to use handles when targeting someone with messages ie @ChetMiller